# '$' not indexing the column when using function in R

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I wrote a function so that I can sum the numbers of columns according to a value in another column, but it would not work. Specifically, I wrote this function to sum values of certain columns of a panel data set according to the year value in the column `year`.

```
make_sum<-function(df,year_vector,varname){
  datalist = list()
  datalist[[1]]<-year_vector
  # define the vectors for storage
  vector_1<-c()
  vector_2<-c()
  vector_3<-c()
  for (i in 1:length(year_vector)){
    vector_1[i]<-sum(df$sum[df$year == year_vector[i]])
    vector_2[i]<-sum(df$varname[df$year == year_vector[i]])
  }
  # vector_3 as the proportion
  vector_3<-vector_2/vector_1
  # save vectors in the datalist
  datalist[[2]]<-vector_1
  datalist[[3]]<-vector_2
  datalist[[4]]<-vector_3
  names(datalist)<-c("year","sum","soc_wel_sum","prop")
  return(datalist)
}
```

However, when I run the function on the year_vector and the data frame, I get 0s for `vector_2`:

```
one<-make_sum(panel_1,c(2004:2007),"社会中介服务业")
> one
$year
[1] 2004 2005 2006 2007

$sum
[1] 124477 135157 149316 160921

$soc_wel_sum
[1] 0 0 0 0

$prop
[1] 0 0 0 0
```

So, I'm not sure why this is happening, because the `varname` is indicated correctly:

```
> panel_1$"社会中介服务业"
  [1]   2   8 105  35  44 106 130   2  25 167  16  56   7
 [14]  39 495  79  74 112  18  15   4   3  84  12  20   0
 [27]  25  58  11  17   8  NA  14  69   8  32  35  39  23
 [40]  18 148  44  39  26  47 240 109  87  43  18   3   4
 [53]   3  93  10  13  NA  24  30  19  25  11   2  22  79
 [66]  21  36  36  34  26  25 170  55  43  14  31 424  97
 [79] 185  47  55   4   7  13  75  16  15  NA  53  32   9
 [92]  30   8   2  13  69  38  40  25  44  23  39 252  41
[105]  36  10  25 522 139 294  37  39   6   5  24  71  17
[118]  15  NA  37  38  43  45   7
```

Comment: Use `df[[varname]]`. You can't use `$` with variables on the right.

Comment: @MrFlick Worked, thank you!